# Get date field from Sharepoint list using Microsoft.Graph library c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Previously we used Microsoft.Sharepoint.CSOM library to get time zone information from SharePoint:

```
var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
var spTimeZone = ctx.Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone;
ctx.Load(spTimeZone);

// 2.Resolve System.TimeZoneInfo from Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.TimeZone 
var fixedTimeZoneName = spTimeZone.Description.Replace("and", "&");
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().FirstOrDefault(tz => tz.DisplayName == fixedTimeZoneName);
var dayItems = items.Select(x => x.FieldValues).ToList();
var date = (DateTime)dayItems.First()["ApplicableDay"];
var specifiedDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(relevantGasDay, timeZone);
```

With such an approach, we received exactly the same date as the user input.

For now, we have the following:

```
var ctx = new GraphServiceClient(_tokenCredential);
var listQuery = ctx.Sites[site].Lists[listName];
var list = await listQuery.Request().GetAsync();
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("expand", "fields")
}
var listItems = await listQuery.Items.Request(queryOptions).GetAsync();
var dayitems = listItems.Select(listItem => listItem.Fields.AdditionalData);
var date = dayItems.First()["ApplicableDay"];
```

`AdditionalData` contains each line of the list as a dictionary. And one of the values is a date

I want to get the date exactly as the user input. How can I achieve this using `Microsoft.Graph` version `4.40.0`? Does there any request to get regional settings?

Answer (score 0):

For now, my users are in one time zone. So, I overcame this with the following code:

```
    var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time")
    var relevantDay = Convert.ToDateTime(item["ApplicableDay"].ToString());
    var unspecified = DateTime.SpecifyKind(relevantDay, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    var time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(unspecified, timeZone);
```

But still, I want to get time zone info from the Microsoft Graph if possible.